Imbalanced dataset with multiple classes
I have an imbalanced dataset with multiple classes where some have less than 100 some are more than 10k,where i want to apply random forest(the dataset is confidential so i cant share),i used all sampling methods to overcome this issue,used all SMOTE techniques,done hyper tuning and all but my f1score is still 40% ,what should i do, is there any new advanced techniques are there or any research articles or journals about this problem, ?????

Don't use accuracy, precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity, or the F1 score. Every criticism at the following threads applies equally to all of these, and indeed to all evaluation metrics that rely on hard classifications:
Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?
Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?
Classification probability threshold

Instead, use probabilistic classifications, and evaluate these using proper scoring rules. Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling, undersampling or weighting will not solve this non-problem:
Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?
And this Meta.CV thread contains a curated list of useful links on imbalanced data.

Also, whatever you do, you may simply have reached the limit of your dataset's predictability: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless/222189#222189

“Hopeless” doesn’t even necessarily describe this situation. An $F_1$ of $40%$ isn’t perfect, but it might not be so bad. @deepakkumar Why do you see that score as unacceptable?
